# Join query returns empty result

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, join

i'm trying to join a few tables together with following code

```
  var result = (from n in db.tbl_NAWs
                join s in db.Status on n.Status equals s.StatusID
                join a in db.tbl_Afdelings on n.Afdeling equals a.ID_Afdeling
                join l in db.Locaties on n.Locatie equals l.LocatieID
                select new NAW_Dto()
                {
                    ClassNR = n.ClassNr,
                    Status = s.Beschrijving,
                    Client = n.Aanspreekvorm,
                    Locatie = l.Naam,
                    Afdeling = a.Afdeling,
                    KamerNr = n.Kamernummer
                }).ToList();
```

But it keeps on returning empty, any ideas ?

Comment: We can't guess your classes/db structure, nore your data. So...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this....

```
  var result = (from n in db.tbl_NAWs
                join s in db.Status on n.Status equals s.StatusID
                join a in db.tbl_Afdelings on n.Afdeling equals a.ID_Afdeling
                join l in db.Locaties on n.Locatie equals l.LocatieID
                select new 
                {
                    ClassNR = n.ClassNr,
                    Status = s.Beschrijving,
                    Client = n.Aanspreekvorm,
                    Locatie = l.Naam,
                    Afdeling = a.Afdeling,
                    KamerNr = n.Kamernummer
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you highlight the difference? I can only see that you've removed the type name, and I'm not sure why that would change things - as long as there's a default constructor and properties to populate his other class should be fine.

Comment: You're right _Rup_. And we also have to consider like how _Jakub Konecki_ has replied.

Answer (score 0):

Run Sql Profiler, check what is the actual SQL query that is being executed and look at your data.

Can't tell why you have empty resultset without seeing your data. Are your foreign key set up the way you think they are?

Try executing this query with some joins removed - you will be able to find the offending join this way.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into TSQL and run it in SSMS 
Remove the comments one at a time and see which does not match

```
select n.ClassNr
-- , s.Beschrijving
-- , a.Afdeling
-- , l.Naam
from tbl_NAWs as n
-- join Status as s on n.Status equals s.StatusID
-- join tbl_Afdelings as a on n.Afdeling equals a.ID_Afdeling
-- join Locaties as l on n.Locatie equals l.LocatieID
```